# Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(n+1)^{1\over 2}\over n^2+2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(n+1)^{1\over 2}\over n^2+2}$.

I think the comparison test is useful. However, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

First do it roughly: if $n$ is large then
$$\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}}{n^2+2}\approx \frac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\ ,$$
and $\sum 1/n^{3/2}$ converges, so we expect that the given sum converges.  NB: **expect**, we still need to give a detailed formal proof.  Here is one possibility.

For $n\ge1$ we have
$$(n+1)^{1/2}\le(n+n)^{1/2}=2^{1/2}n^{1/2}$$
and
$$n^2+2\ge n^2\ ,$$
so
$$\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}}{n^2+2}\le\frac{2^{1/2}n^{1/2}}{n^2}=\frac{2^{1/2}}{n^{3/2}}\ .$$
It is known that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
converges; therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{1/2}}{n^{3/2}}$$
converges (constant multiple); therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^{1/2}}{n^2+2}$$
converges (comparison test).

Comment: I understand everything except how/why ${(n+1)^{1/2}\over n^2+2} \le {2^{1/2}\over n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: BTW I notice that you have asked 7 questions here and have not accepted any answers.  If you get an acceptable answer (mine or someone else's), you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

Each term is about
$\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}
= \dfrac1{n^{3/2}}
$
and the sum of these converges.

Comment: Since the numerator is dominated by $n^{1\over 2}$ and the denominator is dominated by $n^2$, then we can compare the series to ${1\over n^{3\over 2}}$?

Comment: Yep, with different constants that do not matter for showing convergence: top $< \sqrt{2n}$ and bottom $> n^2$.